# Large index match with multiple criteria, duplicate values

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have managed to extract the top 10 scores from a table (tblData), with the parameters being:

1. *Type* = LPR
2. *Year* = this year (TYEAR)
3. *QTR* = this quarter in the financial year (QUARTER)
4. The A Column holds the positions 1 - 10
   by using the **LARGE** function.

```
{=LARGE(IF((tblData[Type]=LPR)*(tblData[Year]=TYEAR)*(tblData[QTR]=QUARTER),tblData[Score]),$A7)}
```

I now need to extract, from tblData (the original table) the matching information from each Row where the Top 10 scores are located.

Using the INDEX and MATCH functions I have the following to extract the data from Column 3 in the table.:

```
{=INDEX(tblData[#All],MATCH(1,(tblData[Type]=LPR)*(tblData[Year]=TYEAR)*(tblData[QTR]=QUARTER)*(tblData[Score]=$B7),0),3)}
```

This works well until there is a duplicate Score in the Top 10. Then I get the same information from tblData column 3 against both scores.

I know the answer is staring me in the face!

My Raw Data:

[image: My Raw Data]

My Output:

[image: My Output]

tblData:

[image: tblData]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72166/discussion-on-question-by-wiernixie-large-index-match-with-multiple-criteria-du).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a modified formula from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528624/extracting-the-top-5-maximum-values-in-excel)

```
=INDEX(tblData[Code], MATCH(1, INDEX((tblData[Score]=LARGE(IF((tblData[Type]=LPR)*(tblData[Year]=TYEAR)*(tblData[QTR]=QUARTER),tblData[Score]),$A7))*(COUNTIF(C$1:C1, tblData[Code])=0),),0))`
```

### Explanation

This formula creates a top-10 table, then lookup the appropriate Code string. `(COUNTIF(C$1:C1, tblData[Code])=0)` this part looks on current column, and see if a specific Code string is already inserted. If it is already inserted, then it find the next occurrence.

For example, if both `ABC` and `DEF` has a value of 9, the column will show the 4th position is `ABC`. When it tries to look up the value of 9, that part of the formula knows that `ABC` is already within the column, so it will find the next Code string with the value of 9, that is `DEF`. So now at 5th position it shows `DEF`.

Comment: Thank you very much @Vylix, your explanation is very clear. It worked. Much appreciated.

Comment: @WierNixie if an answer worked for you, you can tick the answer as the accepted answer. You can also upvote the answer if you like it. Welcome to SuperUser!

Comment: Thank you very much @Vylix, your explanation is very clear. It worked. Much appreciated. Now I need to reverse the process to get the bottom 10. I have created the first column which has the correct SCORE.  But I am struggling with the modified formula.

Comment: I tried this after changing the variables that fed into TYEAR and QTR and it doesn't work every time, am investigating further

Comment: Just change large to small

Comment: Thank you @Vulix, I did that, but was experiencing errors. I am trying to ascertain if there is any 'dirty' data.

Comment: You can make another post and include the error.